# Why does this std::vector::emplace_back fail?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

I'm coming across a compiler error that says:

> attempting to reference a deleted function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Container
{
    Container() = default;
    Container(const Container& other) = delete;
    Container(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    T* ptr;
    ~Container() { delete ptr; }

};

struct Foo { Foo(int a, int b) {} };

int main()
{
    std::vector<Container<Foo>> myvector;
    myvector.push_back(new Foo(1, 2)); // I understand why this doesn't work.
    myvector.emplace_back((new Foo(1, 2))); // I don't understand why this fails

}
```

I understand why it says attempting to reference a *deleted constructor* when I do `std::vector::push_back()`, because this does a copy and needs to call the *copy constructor*, which I deleted.

But `std::vector::emplace_back()` is supposed to take the constructor arguments of the type it holds. When I emplace back, I give it a pointer to a `Foo`, and this should be forwarded to the `Container::Container(T* ptr)` constructor.

What am I missing?

Comment: Defining a copy constructor will not define an implicit move constructor; You require either a copy constructor or a move constructor to `emplace*` an object into a vector

Comment: @WhiZTiM Oh, emplace_back moves the argument? I thought it directly calls the constructor using placement new or something like that, directly constructs it.

Comment: It doesn't, but it might trigger a resize, and *that* has to be able to move or copy elements.

Comment: @Zebrafish It may call move constructor for existing vector items.

Comment: @VTT Ohhh, I see, this is in case it has to reallocate the vector...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Declaring a User-Defined *copy constructor* will not define an implicit *move constructor*; `T` must either have a *copy constructor* or a *move constructor* to `push_back` or `emplace_back*` an object into a `std::vector<T>`.

From the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), see the requirements on `T` to instantiate a `std::vector<T>`. (No restriction here, read on) ..*emphasis mine*

> ***The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container***. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of Erasable, ***but many member functions impose stricter requirements***. This container (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements.

From [`std::vector<...>::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> Type requirements
>
> - `T` must meet the requirements of *CopyInsertable* in order to use overload (1).
> - `T` must meet the requirements of *MoveInsertable* in order to use overload (2).

From [`std::vector<...>::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

> Type requirements
>
> - `T` (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of *MoveInsertable* and *EmplaceConstructible*.

For `emplace_back` here, your code would fulfill the *EmplaceConstructible* criteria, however, because reallcations can happen, you **must** equally fulfill ***MoveInsertable***.